# Python code KeyError trying to read from a JSON file

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

Hello I have a python code to try to read from a JSON file some elements. This code to process some files form a JSON file:

```
with open('C:/asg/response2.json') as json_file:
    data2 = json.load(json_file)

if 'priceResponse' in data2:    
    item = data2['priceResponse']['PriceAvailabilityList'][0]
    property_valuesa.append(item['totalQuantity'])
    property_values2a.append(item['PriceAvailabilityList']['price'])
    
print (property_valuesa)
input ("key enter")
```

The error I receive is:

```
property_valuesa.append(item['totalQuantity'])
KeyError: 'totalQuantity'
```

What is needed to change in code to fix the error and that reads the “totalQuantity” element? For the order of the values is what I tried but I don’t have results.

This is an example of the JSON file I’m reading:

```
{
    "priceResponse": {
        "customerNo": "2312312",
        "userName": "23131@er.com",
        "PriceAvailabilityList": [
            {
                "sku": "12133223",
                "mfgPN": "DELL-sdad",
                "status": "Not authorized to buy",
                "GlobalProductStatusCode": "Not authorized to buy",
                "lineNumber": "1"
            },
            {
                "sku": "38384774",
                "mfgPN": "DELL-E322323H",
                "mfgCode": "23232",
                "status": "Active",
                "description": "27 MON 323232",
                "GlobalProductStatusCode": "Active",
                "price": "195.72",
                "totalQuantity": "138",
                "AvailabilityByWarehouse": [
                    {
                        "warehouseInfo": {
                            "number": "123",
                            "zipcode": "23344",
                            "city": "test, TT",
                            "addr": "testaddress"
                        },
                        "qty": "0"
                    },
                    {
                        "warehouseInfo": {
                            "number": "123",
                            "zipcode": "2344",
                            "city": "TEST, TT",
                            "addr": "testaddress Drive"
                        },
                        "qty": "0"
                    },
                    {
                        "warehouseInfo": {
                            "number": "233",
                            "zipcode": "213",
                            "city": "TEST, te",
                            "addr": "testaddress Pkwy"
                        },
                        "qty": "138"
                    },
                    {
                        "warehouseInfo": {
                            "number": "243",
                            "zipcode": "34324",
                            "city": "test, tets",
                            "addr": "test Way"
                        },
                        "qty": "0"
                    },
                    {
                        "warehouseInfo": {
                            "number": "2312",
                            "zipcode": "2312",
                            "city": "test, TS",
                            "addr": "test"
                        },
                        "qty": "0"
                    }
                ],
                "lineNumber": "1"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`PriceAvailabilityList` is a list containing a number of dictionaries. The `KeyError` occurs because the code expects `totalQuantity` to be a key in the first dictionary:

```
item = data2['priceResponse']['PriceAvailabilityList'][0]
property_valuesa.append(item['totalQuantity'])
```

`totalQuantity` is a key in the *second* dictionary in `PriceAvailabilityList`.